#CKEditor5 #ckeditor How to add math formular on ckeditor using django
I am finding it difficult to add plugins on my ckeditor using django
please can any one help me with the steps to accomplish this.
always showing me the diffault on django-ckeditor-5 cant i resize or zoom
enter image description here
CKEDITOR_5_CONFIGS = {    'default': {        'toolbar':'full',
    },    'extends': {        'blockToolbar': [            'paragraph', 'heading1', 'heading2', 'heading3',            '|',            'bulletedList', 'numberedList',            '|',            'blockQuote',        ],        'toolbar': ['heading', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'underline', 'strikethrough',        'code','subscript', 'superscript', 'highlight', '|', 'codeBlock', 'sourceEditing', 'insertImage',                    'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList', '|',  'blockQuote', 'imageUpload', '|',                    'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', 'mediaEmbed', 'removeFormat',                    'insertTable', 'FindAndReplace',],        'image': {            'toolbar': ['imageTextAlternative', '|', 'imageStyle:alignLeft',                        'imageStyle:alignRight', 'imageStyle:alignCenter', 'imageStyle:side',  '|'],            'styles': [                'full',                'side',                'alignLeft',                'alignRight',                'alignCenter',            ]
        },        'table': {            'contentToolbar': [ 'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells',            'tableProperties', 'tableCellProperties' ],            'tableProperties': {                'borderColors': customColorPalette,                'backgroundColors': customColorPalette            },            'tableCellProperties': {                'borderColors': customColorPalette,                'backgroundColors': customColorPalette            }        },        'heading' : {            'options': [                { 'model': 'paragraph', 'title': 'Paragraph', 'class': 'ck-heading_paragraph' },                { 'model': 'heading1', 'view': 'h1', 'title': 'Heading 1', 'class': 'ck-heading_heading1' },                { 'model': 'heading2', 'view': 'h2', 'title': 'Heading 2', 'class': 'ck-heading_heading2' },                { 'model': 'heading3', 'view': 'h3', 'title': 'Heading 3', 'class': 'ck-heading_heading3' }            ]        }    },    'list': {        'properties': {            'styles': 'true',            'startIndex': 'true',            'reversed': 'true',        }    }}

